# Can't run Appium Inspector with .ipa file

Tags: ios, appium, ipa, ios-ui-automation

When I launch the Inspector, I see that the app is blinking and closing for 3 times, and then I got these error:

[image]

[image]

It worked fine with Android apk file. I am not familiar with .ipa file.

Comment: Can you manually install this ipa this device and see if its working?? This is the problem with ipa file only.

Comment: @PankajKatiyar I manually installed this ipa successfully on this iPhone, and it's working as expected

Comment: Did it work by my answer?? let me know if it doesn't. Thanks

Comment: is .ipa file still supported for appium inspector?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have an `*.ipa` file path correctly set in the Appium Settings

[image]

Comment: Yes, file path is correct, that's why it could be installed on device, but for some reasons, it's closed real fast

Comment: Seems like is something wrong with the way this IPA file was signed before building

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have developer signed before building the ipa..

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you don't have a permission to do. The .ipa should build with developer certificate.

Comment: I tried to re-sign the certificate, by using AppResigner and some command lines I found on here, but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are running test on iPhone device and the .ipa file you have is working fine with valid certificate:
then on mobile --> Go to Settings --> Developer --> Enable UI Automation --> On and the run your test, it should be okay.

Comment: I knew all these settings, I even tried to re-sign certificate, but still it doesn't work. Thanks for your answer